# Change photo date from BC to AD

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

On macOS 10.15.3 I’d like to adjust the date metadata of some pictures.

How do I change the date of all photos and videos in Photos.app from BC to AD?

Comment: Just how long _have_ you had these photos?